# How to delete files bigger than x kb with powershell script

Tags: powershell

I need to write a Powershell script that will delete files larger than 80 megabytes. All these files are in the same folder. I found a very similar solved question on overstackflow, and I have already used all the answers and comments from there, but none of them worked. Probably, in the period from 2019 to 2023, the approach to variable properties changed in Powershell, because now this code:

```
$dir = 'C:\<path-to-file>\logs'

$minSize = 80000000

echo $minSize
Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Recurse | where { ! $_.PSIsContainer } | % { $_.FullName } | ForEach-Object{
    if ($_.Length -gt $minSize){
        Remove-Item $_
    }else{
        echo '$_ is too small to delete'
    }
}
```

when executed, assigns a variable value that is the length of the string, not the weight of the file. The same code is a working answer to this question that I found.

I've read a lot of documentation and forums, but I still don't understand why the code takes the length of the string. Please help, Powershell experts!

Powershell Version: 5.1.14393.5582

Comment: Just delete the `% {$_.FullName} |` section. This reduces the found files to their Path.